The Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process from modified integrand
Suppose that $\alpha > 0$ and $\sigma \in \mathbb{R}$ are fixed. Define $Y(t), t \geq 0$ to be an adapted modification of the Itô integral
$$
Y(t) = \sigma e^{-\alpha t} \int_0^t e^{\alpha s} dB(s)
$$
with a.s. continuous paths. I want to show that $Y(t)$ satisfies
$$
dY(t) = -\alpha Y(t) dt + \sigma dB(t).
$$
I was trying to write $Z(t) = \int_0^t e^{\alpha s} dB(s)$ and then use Ito's lemma to $f(t, Z(t))$ as $Y(t) = \sigma e^{-\alpha t} Z(t)$ but got stuck. Is this is a right approach?

Yes. Why stuck?
